# Printing to Windows network printer in Perl WITHOUT shell command

Tags: windows, perl, printing

I have a printer, an HP DeskJet 712C, shared via a Windows XP workstation.  I am able to print to this printer from various applications, but I am unable to print to it (from the workstation the printer is attached to or any other) via the `PRINT` shell command.  I have a Perl script, currently hosted on a Windows 7 workstation, that generates text files.  I would like those text files printed to the aforementioned printer, but as I am unable to use the `PRINT` shell command, I don't know how.  How can I print these text files to that printer in Perl?

Comment: I'd like to avoid spawning Word if possible, but if that's the only way to do it, then that's how I'll do it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about windows programming, but there are a couple of options I can think of.

1. [Printer](https://metacpan.org/module/Printer) - There is a module on CPAN called **[Printer](https://metacpan.org/module/Printer)** that claims to handle windows printing.  I haven't used it. YMMV, but it looks like exactly what you want.
2. [Wx](https://metacpan.org/module/Wx) - The Wx GUI toolkit has nice, windows compatible printing capabilities.  It, sadly, is also a huge, complex dependency to add just for a simple command line script.  I have used this and it works very nicely.
3. [Win32::API](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32%3a%3aAPI) - Here's where my Windows ignorance really shows. The Win32::API module lets you call into windows DLLs.  If you know the appropriate functions/DLLs to use, you could access them to get a print job started.

---

**Update**

You might want to check out [this thread](http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl-win32-users/32704/) on ActiveState's Perl-Win32 users' list.

Apparently you can just do:

```
open my $prn, '>', '//mycomputer/PrinterShare' or die "Oh noes $!";
print $prn "Here's some text to print.";
```

This is untested, untried, and maybe untrue, but give it a shot.  What could possibly go wrong? Printers are cheap these days. ;)

Comment: The trouble with Win32::API is that I don't know *what* functions / DLLs to use, and I have as yet been unable to find good documentation on that subject. I'm sure there's some way I can blame Microsoft for this. ;)

Comment: @KitPeters, I poked a bit at the MSDN docs online, and they've Windows-8-ized them all to hell and I can't find a thing anymore...

Comment: Can you link to the Wk toolkit?  I think it's either that or Ghostscript at this point.

Comment: Ugh, I am a moron, I meant Wx. https://metacpan.org/module/Wx  Have you tried opening a printer share as a file handle yet?  That looks like the easiest approach.  Have you tried `Printer`?  That looks pretty close.  Wx will mean adapting your code to a complex GUI environment.  But if that's what it takes to make it work, and it's worth it to you.

Comment: I wasn't able to get `Printer` to work, and opening the share as a file handle doesn't work on that printer.  I'll check out Wx, because I can see some potential applications thereof.